# "Differential graded homological algebra" by Avramov, Foxby and Halperin

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra

I am looking for "Differential graded homological algebra" by L. Avramov, H. Foxby, and S. Halperin, which is widely cited as a preprint o as a manuscript, e.g. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=L.L.%20Avramov,%20H.-B.%20Foxby,%20S.%20Halperin,%20Differential%20Graded%20Homological%20Algebra,%20manuscript

I don't know whether it has been pusblished with a different title or if it is available somewhere online. Thank you

Comment: This book was not published, and as far as I know, the authors stopped working on it, so there are only drafts circulating privately.

Comment: I would also like to access this text